# Why does the cookie consent popup keep showing up despite saving preferences multiple times?

Tags: support, bug, cookies

Maybe this has been asked before. Maybe not - nothing in my choice for title popped up.

This has to be **at least** the fourth time in the last few weeks that I've been asked about my cookie choices. (I've answered each and every one the same way - customize, accept nothing but what is forced.)

Why am I **continually** being asked this?

Safari 14.0.3, Big Sur 11.2.3.... not that any of that should actually matter.

It's annoying. Please, can someone either turn this automatic popup off or (a) explain why I am asked to make the same choice repeatedly or (b) well... include in the explanation of choices why you really have to do this?

---

Looking at the comments, I'm seeing nothing on why this keeps happening. Let me update things to macOS 11.4 and Safari 14.1.1. The close link - I did what I said and deleted this - really doesn't answer anything.

Still, nobody has answered why I'm continually being asked to (a) accept all cookies or (b) turn off only three of four options with several clicks - and this happens nearly daily! With the "default" being option A.

No other site I visit cares about this. They may simply *just* do without my acceptance. If that is the case - just tell me. Or tell me to use a different (better?) browser than Safari.

Or fix the issue.

Comment: ^ read through answers and the Uber Meta page collecting bug reports. This was asked to death already. And I am starting to get annoyed that no one on iOS/macOS apparently knows about ITP that retires cookies set via `document.cookie` after a week or so even if they are first-party. Does not mean that it was a bad idea to use a third-party service for that, though.

Comment: @OlegValter, thanks. I'll delete my question - no reason to close it - after I read through the 38 comments to the question you linked to along with the 4 answers. Believe me, I get **your** annoyance. Maybe you could understand mine? Honeywell, SAP, HTML, CSS (along with HTML5), Microsoft, and yes - **Apple**. Never came across ITP, whatever that means. Sorry for not keeping up with cookie settings. Have a GREAT day! (And thanks for the link. It's nearly midnight here and my wife's 4th surgery is tomorrow morning, so please, forgive me if I don't go through whatever ITP is for a day.)

Comment: It's annoying for me as well, idk why every bug report has to be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @dfd - that annoyance is not directed at you personally (no need to get so sarcastic, btw), more at the fact that, apparently, no one using Apple products knows of Apple introducing Intelligent Tracking Protection a couple of years ago which screws up apps/sites relying on third-party services and/or javascript-based setting of cookies. No need to delete the question - there is nothing wrong with being a duplicate. It also reduces chances of another bug report about the same thing (since the search we have here is subpar)

Comment: "With the "default" being option A" - eh, go try convincing SE.  This was brought up several times in the following time period with staff being on the defensive. See [this report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/359493/786798). You can try your luck, but something tells me they'll just ignore you :( P.s. No need to apologize - no grudges held, I removed the irrelevant part from the post

Comment: @dfd - Don’t delete a valid question.  More focus on this extremely annoying behavior should be raised until something is done about it! This issue is more than just iOS despite the annoyingly incorrect claims otherwise

Comment: "why I'm continually being asked" - as to this, you will probably have to slog through all the reports on MSO and MSE to figure this out. There were multiple reports with [different symptoms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bcookies%5d%20is%3aq), but it mostly (if not exclusively) affects macOS/iOS users. I mentioned before that it is probably due to ITP. Since it works per-device, it is difficult to pinpoint exactly what's happening.

Comment: It also affects Windows users using Chromium Edge and Chrome

Comment: @SecurityHound - I guess that depends :) Because it is my exact setup. Although I do not disallow cookies, so that's the reason everything works fine for me.

Comment: @dfd - anyways, don't get me wrong - your frustration is understandable. The choice to use a third-party service for cookie consent is questionable at best, however "trustworthy" SE [finds the said party to be](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/363873/786798). And when it causes so much inconvenience for privacy-conscious users, that's just sad.